# Set different constraints for iPad in portrait and landscape mode

Tags: ios, ipad, storyboard, autolayout, size-classes

When the device is in portrait orientation I have tableView and graphView in a viewController. When i change to landscape mode, i want to display only graphView. I am using size classes to do it. It works for all iPhones.

But for iPad, Size classes for portrait and landscape are same (regular width and height).

I need to set different constraints for portrait and landscape mode.How do i remove tableView when the device is in landscape.

Answer (score 1):

This code may help you:

```
- (void) handleOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) orientation 
{

    if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown)
    {
       //handle the portrait view
    }
    else if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)
    {
      //handle the landscape view
      //write your code for removing Table
    }
}
```

Comment: constraints is handle via storyboard then what is the way?